# Combining two multi-dimentional numpy arrays when one of them encodes the index information, the other encodes the array content

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray

Here is the toy version of the problem I am facing:

Given the following two numpy arrays:

```
img = np.array([[0,1,1,2], [0,2,1,1]])
number = np.array([[0,0.1,0.1,0.2], [0.1,0,0.2,0.2]])
```

both `img` and `number` are 2 by 4 NumPy arrays. You can think of it as 2 participants in a study and 4 trials per participant. `img` encodes which image is presented at each trial, so its element is always an integer (0, 1, or 2) representing an image ID (image #0, #1, or #2), and there are in total 3 candidate images. Each image may occur more than once for each participant as shown in the example.

`number` is also a 2 by 4 NumPy array which encodes some numeric quantity corresponding to each image. You can think of it as a number presented to the participant above the image.

**Within each participant**, the number and image are **uniquely paired**. For example, img[0,1]=img[0,2]=1 means the first participant sees the same image (image #1) in the second and the third trial. Then it must follow that number[0,1]=number[0,2]. However, for the second participant, the pairing may change. While image #1 is paired with 0.1 for the first participant, it is instead paired with 0.2 for the second. The end product I want is something like the following:

```
goal = np.array([[[0,0],[0.1, 0.1],[0.2, 0.2]], [[0.1,0.1],[0.2, 0.2],[0, 0]]])
```

The `goal` is a 2x3x2 NumPy array. 2 again means the 2 participants, 3 means the total amount of unique images used. In this example, 3 unique images are indexed by 0,1, and 2. The third dimension 2 is just repeating the same digit twice, which I do need. Can someone think of a way of doing this in a purely vectorized fashion?

Here is how I would do it using for loop (not exactly syntactically correct):

```
goal = np.empty((2,3,2))
img = extract_first_occurance_of_each_element(img)
number = extract_first_occurance_of_each_element(number)
for subj in range(subjects):
    for trial in range(3):
        img_idx = img[subj, trial]
        goal[subj, img_idx,:] = [number[subj, trial], number[subj, trial]]
```

Comment: Shows us how you'd do it in a not-so purely vectorized fashion!  Don't depend on us understanding your word problem correctly.  Demonstrate the action in a clear sense, even if it isn't "most efficient".

Comment: My apologies. I appended my for-loop solution as pseudo-code in the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Your iteration - cleaned up a bit:

```
In [7]: goal = np.zeros((2,3,2))
   ...: for subj in range(2):
   ...:     for trial in range(3):
   ...:         img_idx = img[subj, trial]
   ...:         goal[subj, img_idx,:] = [number[subj, trial], number[subj, trial]]

In [8]: goal
Out[8]: 
array([[[0. , 0. ],
        [0.1, 0.1],
        [0. , 0. ]],

       [[0.1, 0.1],
        [0.2, 0.2],
        [0. , 0. ]]])
```

Not quite the same as the stated target, but close enough:

```
In [9]: np.array([[[0,0],[0.1, 0.1],[0.2, 0.2]], [[0.1,0.1],[0.2, 0.2],[0, 0]]])
Out[9]: 
array([[[0. , 0. ],
        [0.1, 0.1],
        [0.2, 0.2]],

       [[0.1, 0.1],
        [0.2, 0.2],
        [0. , 0. ]]])
```

With multidimensional indexing:

```
In [26]: subj=np.arange(2)[:,None]; trial=np.arange(3)    
In [27]: img_idx = img[subj, trial]; img_idx
Out[27]: 
array([[0, 1, 1],
       [0, 2, 1]])

In [28]: goal = np.zeros((2,3,2))    
In [29]: goal[subj,img_idx]=np.stack([number[subj,trial], number[subj, trial]], axis=2)

In [30]: goal
Out[30]: 
array([[[0. , 0. ],
        [0.1, 0.1],
        [0. , 0. ]],

       [[0.1, 0.1],
        [0.2, 0.2],
        [0. , 0. ]]])
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! Unfortunately, instead of just indexing the first 3 trials, it is crucial for me to extract all unique pairings of image and number.

Comment: I believe I replicated your 'psuedo code'